# ConnectionString in the web.config to connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I have database locally in the server I am working on creating the Web API. With the windows authentication I am able get in the SQL server and access the database and table from SQL Server Management Studio. But with this connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=NameoftheServer;Initial Catalog=NameofDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User Id=UserIDusedin nManagementStudio;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and the Web API I am giving it as

```
  string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
   DbConnection.Open();
```

But when I try to call the API it throws exception in

[image]

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Login failed for user

[image]

Comment: Add full exception text

Comment: "ClarityDBConnection" should be "DBConnection" in the example

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I copied pasted. I have edited the question. I am giving the same name in both Web.config and in the Controller

Comment: try to login from sql server management studio or visual studio (using SQL Server Object Explorer) with your username and password that you write in your connection string and see is your username and password is correct. You might need to add user to your database or modify password.

Comment: "Login Failed" rang any bells?

Comment: @Backs I edited the question with the full  exception

Comment: after `Login failed for user %user_name%` usually there is a description of error

Comment: No there is no other description it just says Login failed for user 'username'

Comment: possible your sql services stop??

Comment: How do I check the SQL services

Comment: sql server configuration manager

Comment: -> sql server services

Comment: using 'Run" `(windows flag + R)` type `services.msc` + `enter`. Check on the list if your local instance of SQL is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [authentication mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) of your SQL-Server, [edit](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/555332) it if needed.

Maybe, you need to use [Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) in your conneciton string. So, you needn't to set up user id and passowrd in connection string, but need to run your application with credentials of trusted user.

Comment: I tried to check the authentication mode for the server, it is Windows authentication.

Comment: @user4912134 in Windows authentication "...SQL Server does not ask for the password, and does not perform the identity validation..." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: @user4912134 use mixed mode or use integrated security=true

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use myself and its working.

Add

```
name = "DBConnection"
providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString = "Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=User;Password=Password;"

conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

If its not working the problem is maybe in the connection string itself since it can be a little different depending on database.